# RFC 854 canonical terminal defenition

Tags: telnet, rfc

I'm beginning to read [**RFC 854**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) and have one question about it. In this RFC said the following:

> An NVT is an imaginary device which provides a standard, network-wide,
> intermediate representation of a canonical terminal.

So what does mean canonical terminal?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it means a "common, standard terminal". It has features that can be found on most ordinary terminals. For instance, it uses ASCII, because that's the most common character set on real terminals.